# How many pairs (p, m) are there, if p is a prime number and m an integer, such that (m^3-pm+1)/(m^2+pm+2) is an integer

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Tried to guess the answers, because I have no clue on how to start this problem, and got 1 solution, but I doubt that that solution is the only one.

Comment: how did you try? What was your one solution? what about the slightly different problem of $(p, m)$ integers such that $\frac{m^3 -pm +1}{m^2+pm+2}$ is an integer?

Comment: Also what is the motivation behind the weird fraction? fwiw p=2, m = 1 is the only solution i can find. For higher $m$, the remainder is (afaik) 5 :O no such pattern with the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the prime $p$ is odd, whatever the parity of $m$, the denominator is even while the numerator is odd so the quotient cannot be integer.

It remains to settle the question when $ p = 2$. We have
$$\frac{m^3-2m+1}{m^2+2m+2}=m-2+\frac{5}{m^2+2m+2}$$
There are only the following four possibilities to examine $m^2+2m+2=\pm1,\pm5$ then the four equations
$$m^2+2m+1=0 \text{ gives }m=-1\\m^2+2m+3=0\text{ not solution }\\m^2+2m-3=0\text{ gives  } 1\text{ and } -3\\m^2+2m+7=0\text{ not solution }$$

Thus the only solutions are $\color{red}{(p,m)=(2,-1),(2,1),(2,-3)}$. The corresponding quotients are $2, 0$ and $-4$ respectively.